# Caching Video iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, avplayer, avplayeritem

```
  AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithUrl:@"myUrl.mp4"];
  AVPlayerItem * item = [AVPlayerItem itemWithAsset:asset];
  AVPlayer * player  = [AVPlayer playerWithItem:item];
 playerViewController.player = player;
 [player play];
```

How Can i know that asset or item or whatever downloaded video fully.
I need it for future caching it;

Now im using

```
NSData * videoData = [NSData dataWithUrl:myurl.mp4"];
NSCache *cache = [NSCache new];
[cache setObject:videoData forKey:myUrl];
```

And when i retrieve data from nscache i write it to file and play

```
NSData *videoData = [cache objectForKey:myUrl];
[videoData writeToFile:MyPath.mp4 atomically:YES];
```

And then

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileUrlWithPath:mypath];
AVAsset *asset = =[AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
```

..etc and play

But it a little bit slow.
if videoData contains in AVAsset , i can store it or AVPlayerItem .But i need to know when it downloaded.

How can i implement caching in a different way or upgrade this one. Help.

Answer (score 0):

we can download any data from cloud using NSURLSession, Download in progress and completion [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession) fires delegate methods , we can know download completion events and and progression events by using that delegate methods, you can  implement downloading functionality by using [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession) as follows

https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

I have an app with vertical collection view of video items, each item should repeat itself continuously, until swiped up or down.

So I need not to stream file every time *and* not download files that were downloaded earlier.

I came up with slightly different approach:

1. Stream AVURLAsset,
2. When reached end I use AVAssetExportSession to save file to disk,
3. Then I create new AVPLayerItem with new AVAsset using saved file,
4. AVPlayer's replaceCurrentItem(with: <#T##AVPlayerItem?#>)

But this is lame, I guess. I have to steam file two times. First time on first run, and then then when saving file. I'd like to just cache AVAsset into memory for the current application session, so I don't need to keep files.